# Модель не делает предсказания. PyCharm. Machine Learning. SystemError: unknown opcode. model.predict()?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, pycharm, sklearn

**Где искать ошибку?**

*При запуске данного кода на jupyter notebook всё работает. При запуске через PyCharm получаю ошибку. Версия python на JN 3.8.8 на PCh 3.9.7.*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dill
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse, r2_score as r2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def load_model_dill(path):
    # Загрузка модели
    with open(path, "rb") as mod1:
        model_name = dill.load(mod1)
    return model_name


def save_model_dill(path, model_name):
    # Сохранение модели
    with open(path, "wb") as mod:
        dill.dump(model_name, mod)


def evaluate_preds(true_values, pred_values, plot=1):
    """Оценка качества модели и график preds vs true"""

    r2_metrics = round(r2(true_values, pred_values), 3)

    print("R2:\t" + str(r2_metrics) + "\n" +
          "RMSE:\t" + str(round(np.sqrt(mse(true_values, pred_values)), 3)) + "\n" +
          "MSE:\t" + str(round(mse(true_values, pred_values), 3))
          )
    if plot == 1:
        plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

        # sns.scatterplot(x=pred_values, y=true_values.values)
        plt.scatter(pred_values, true_values.values, s=2)
        max_true = max(true_values.values)[0]
        plt.plot([0, max_true], [0, max_true], linestyle='--',
                 color='black')  # диагональ, где true_values = pred_values

        plt.xlabel('Predicted values')
        plt.ylabel('True values')
        plt.title('True vs Predicted values')
        plt.show()
    return r2_metrics


path_to_work_dir = "./"

# Загрузка трейнового и тестового датасетов
X_train = pd.read_csv(path_to_work_dir + "app/X_train.csv")
y_train = pd.read_csv(path_to_work_dir + "app/y_train.csv")

X_test = pd.read_csv(path_to_work_dir + "app/X_test.csv")
y_test = pd.read_csv(path_to_work_dir + "app/y_test.csv")

# Загрузка модели
model_gbr_load = load_model_dill(path_to_work_dir + "app/models/GBR_model.dill")

# Расчет предсказаний по тестовой выборке
y_test_preds = model_gbr_load.predict(X_test)
# Вывод метрик на печать
r2_gbr = evaluate_preds(y_test, y_test_preds)
```

C:\Python3\python.exe "C:/Новая папка/Project/first/load_model.py"
XXX lineno: 140, opcode: 158

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Новая папка\Project\first\load_model.py", line 60, in 
y_test_preds = model_gbr_load_1.predict(X_test)

File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 507, in predict
Xt = transform.transform(Xt)

File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_set_output.py", line 140, in wrapped
data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 1305, in transform
Xs = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(

File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py", line 65, in **call**
return super().**call**(iterable_with_config)

File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1863, in **call**
return output if self.return_generator else list(output)

File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1792, in _get_sequential_output
res = func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py", line 127, in **call**
return self.function(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 933, in _transform_one
res = transformer.transform(X)

File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 689, in transform
Xt = transform.transform(Xt)

File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_set_output.py", line 140, in wrapped
data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_set_output.py", line 140, in wrapped
data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_set_output.py", line 140, in wrapped
data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)

**SystemError: unknown opcode**

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос описание работы кода.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что пишут на [англоязычном СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73297667/8324991):

> Code objects (from functions and class methods) serialized with dill are not guaranteed to work across different Python versions, because the list of valid opcodes change from version to version. In cases where there is an opcode unknown to the interpreter deserializing ("unpickling") the code object, the functions and classes are successfully recreated, but fail to execute as in your example.

Суть в том, что сериализация кода через `dill` не гарантирует работу десериализованного кода на другой версии Питона. Сам код классов и функций будет успешно воссоздан, но при этом может не выполниться, поскольку разные версии Питона используют разные `opcode`. Рекомендация тут может быть только использовать одну и ту же версию Питона и вообще полностью одинаковую среду выполнения.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду тогда использовать, одну IDE. Просто, тогда странно получается, если например, модель обучена на том же Google colabotary, где версия питона 3.10 и после загружена Github, то дальнейшее использование такой модели возможно только через Google colabotary.

Comment: Ну нет, вы просто можете поднять в `Docker` нужную версию `Python` и всё там будет работать. Ну или локально её поставить. Вы можете иметь много разных версий у себя локально, почитайте про окружения Питона. Просто запускайте код в окружении с такой же версией.

Comment: Понял. Буду тогда оборачивать все в Docker. Об этом надо ещё почитать.